# Search for non-existing tags shows all entries

Tags: templating, relations, tags

I have 3 groups of tags that redirect to the same template. `tags/index.html`. All the routing and linking those tags to their group page works well.

`<a href="{{ siteUrl }}taggroup/{{ tag.slug }}"`

The problem I have is that when I try to enter a tag that doesn't exist on the address bar (e.g., http://sitename/taggroup/unknowntag) I get all entries displayed.

Here's my `tags/index.html` code:

```
{% if not tag %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

{% set tag = craft.tags.slug(tag).first %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).order('title').limit(null) %}

 {% if entries | length %}

  {% for entry in entries %}

    <!-- Code Here -->

  {% endfor %}

  {% else %}

   <!-- No Tag Code Here -->

 {% endif %}
```

What Am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is only logical. Your `tag` will be null so your query is actually 
`{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(null).order('title').limit(null) %}` and that results in 
`{% set entries = craft.entries.order('title').limit(null) %}`
So in the end you will fetch all entries. 
This is what you need

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.slug(tag).first %}
<!-- check if the tag exists -->
{% if tag %}
    <!-- the length filter actually fetches all entries -> executes the query and caches all entries
    so you can just fetch them in the beginning. You'll gain no performance boost with that filter -->
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).order('title').limit(null).find() %}
    {% if entries %}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <!-- code here you fetched entries -->
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <!-- you have a tag but no entries related to that tag -->
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <!-- you have no tag -> you won't find any entries -->
{% endif %}
```